# Creating random matrix with rules in R

Tags: r

I need to create a random matrix from the values below which will contain two basic rules:

1) Each column must contains only one value where remaining will be zeros and

2) each row must be occupied by only one value.

```
# create dummy matrix
B = matrix( 
  c(83, 101, 75, 182, 150, 199,
    218,  80,   90, 138,    249,    299,
    113,  171,  146,    226,    40.4,   78,
    314,    116,    186,    33.2,   345,    196,
    327,    189,    199,    109,    359,    281,
    430,    292,    302,    232,    461,    404    
  ), ncol=6, nrow=6)
# Transpose
t(B)
# names for cols and rows
colnames(B) <- c("x1",  "x2",   "x3",   "x4",   "x5",   "x6")
rownames(B) <- c("y1",  "y2",  "y3",    "y4",   "y5",   "y6")
```

Every possible combination of that arrangement is the output

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
y1  83  0   0   0   0   0
y2  0   0   90  0   0   0
y3  0   171 0   0   0   0
y4  0   0   0   0   345 0
y5  0   0   0   109 0   0
y6  0   0   0   0   0   404
```

and e.g.

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
y1  0   101 0   0   0   0
y2  218 0   0   0   0   0
y3  0   0   146 0   0   0
y4  0   0   0   0   345 0
y5  0   0   0   109 0   0
y6  0   0   0   0   0   404
```

and so forth...

Please, is there any elegant solution, how to do that. Any advice or help is very appreciated. Thanks a lot in forward.

Comment: You just need a random matrix once, or you want to create all the possible matrices?

Comment: Yes, I want to create all the possible matrices.

Comment: I don't know about the idea of creating so many matrices, but creating a single random matrix could be done using matrix indexing as follows `rows <- sample(nrow(B)) ;  B[-(rows + (seq(ncol(B)) - 1)*nrow(B))] <- 0 ; B`

Comment: This seems to be very good approach, only create all the possible matrices by loop and then store particular matrices into list... I have no idea, how to do that.

Comment: I was wondering about something like this...

multiarray = list();
for (i in 1:100) {
  B1 <- B
  rows <- sample(nrow(B1)) ; B1[-(rows + (seq(ncol(B1)) - 1)*nrow(B1))] <- 0
  multiarray[[i]] = B1;
}

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work... possition of values is changing and I want to fix them.

Comment: With transpose, this doesn't work... possition of values is changing. So thanks a lot David, your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a diagonal matrix and then permute rows or columns. In case of single random permutation `sample(n)` would suffice, for all of them - `allPerms`.

```
n <- 3  # dimension
mat <- diag(1:n)

permute::allPerms(n) -> perms
mat[perms[k, ], ]   # k-th permutation
```

Downside is that all permutations are generated and saved.

Comment: Yes, but there is a probability one row contains more than one values, which I don't want to.

Comment: @MartinSmith it is impossible. If diagonal values are 1,2,...k, then permutation P puts value i to P(i). Two rows/columns have a non zero number if P(i) = P(j) for some i and j. Contradiction with P being permutation.

Comment: Thanks I seet it... I was wondering about concept that I've written to David threat.